# Javascript/jssh issue Firefox 4.0b1

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, dom-events, jssh

I built jssh for Firefox 4.0b1 and packaged as an xpi and installed it to my browser, when running Javascript that checks `<td>` tags for a certain phrase in the `onclick` or `onfocus` events. I am getting an NS_ERROR that says component not available; has anyone seen this happen as of yet? It only happens when the `<td>` tag is either not the first one on the page or is not in the first `<tr>`. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSSh is unmaintained code and has now been dropped from the firefox builds and has to be downloaded separately, no one has currently picked up development so it looks like JSSh is just going to die. Although this issue was related to an error in the 4.0b1 javascript engine and has since been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

New xpi of JSSH for Mozila 4.0 and higher (v21) is uploaded to
http://abstracta.com.uy/en/descargas-2.html

this JSSH version is developed over MozRepl and simulates exactly JSSH Console
SourceCode is open at https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/mozrepl-jssh